Version 2 Objective-C ABI may not be mixed with earlier versions
I am unable to compile and run a Obj-C program on Ubuntu
Enviroment:
Ubuntu Version: 22.04, 24.04
clang -v output:
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64

Build Command:
clang++ -o checker checker.mm \
-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include \
-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib \
-I/usr/local/include \
-isystem /usr/include/GNUstep \
-isystem /usr/local/include/GNUstep \
-L/usr/local/lib \
-fobjc-runtime=gnustep-2.0 \
-lssl -lcrypto -lgnustep-base -lobjc

Log with LD_DEBUG=libs shows that the lib at /usr/local/lib/libobjc.so.4.6 might be the reason, so I tried to compile that as well, first with
cd ~
wget https://github.com/gnustep/libobjc2/archive/v2.2.1.tar.gz
tar xvzf v2.2.1.tar.gz
cd libobjc2-2.2.1
mkdir build
cd build
export CC=`which clang`
export CXX=`which clang++`
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
ldconfig

Which, didn't work, then with script from https://github.com/plaurent/gnustep-build/tree/master which didn't resolve the issue either, right now I'm at a blind for what could be going on with my program.
Any and every help will be appriciated, thank you
